# On the distinction between "objecthood" and "knowability" in Kantian philosophy

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics

> What pre-Copernican philosophy treats as two distinct
>   matters-**objecthood** and **knowability**-are thus [in Kant's CPR] treated as
>   one.
>
> [...]
>
> In pre-Copernican philosophy, there is a clear conceptual division
>   between **the question of metaphysics / ontology** (what is the
>   constitution of reality?) and **the question of epistemology** (how do we
>   attain knowledge of reality?). These two sets of concerns are bound to
>   be intermixed in any worthwhile philosophical system, but they remain
>   from the pre-Copernican point of view separable in principle, due to
>   *the detachability of knowability from objecthood* to which
>   pre-Copernican philosophy is committed.

(Sebastian Gardner, [*Routledge Philosophy GuideBook to Kant and the Critique of Pure Reason*](https://books.google.ro/books?id=tNoqBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=objecthood%20and%20knowability&source=bl&ots=MJ425PrsvU&sig=pbg0Ija9HcFLBxkz31Xv1SD3G70&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnltWZyJLVAhUEJ8AKHdWmBWYQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=objecthood%20and%20knowability&f=false), p. 39)

The way I understand this text is that **objecthood** relates to **the question of metaphysics / ontology**, and that **knowability** relates to **the question of epistemology**. This is is the kind of direct connection that I understand this text to make between these two terminological pairs.

Am I then correct in assuming that **objecthood** is the subject-matter of **metaphysics / ontology**, and that **knowability** is the subject-matter of **epistemology** (conclusion also based on the etymology of the words "ontology" and "epistemology")?

Comment: The point of him (valid as well for - more modern - Rorty and Putnam) is that ontology and epistemology are intimitely interrelated, i.e. we can know things only insofar as we know them as properties of objects and they are only objects insofar we (can) know of them. Thus, e.g. freedom, world, soul and God are no objects. Is you question really only about the terminology (body of the question), or is it about kantian philosophy and how they are interrelated (title of the question)? Because these are two different pairs of shoes, really.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking First of all, about the terminology, to make sure I have understood the text correctly.

Comment: At first sight, I would say: correct. See [Ontology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ontology/#Ont): "As a first approximation, ontology is the study of what there is [i.e. "*objects*"]. Some contest this formulation of what ontology is, so it's only a first approximation. Many classical philosophical problems are problems in ontology: the question whether or not there is a god, or the problem of the existence of universals, etc.. These are all problems in ontology in the sense that they deal with whether or not a certain thing, or more broadly entity, exists. "

Comment: vs [Epistemology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemology/): "As the study of knowledge, epistemology is concerned with the following questions: What are the necessary and sufficient conditions of knowledge? What are its sources? What is its structure, and what are its limits?"

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You say: _At first sight, I would say: correct._ Does that mean you're implying that at a deeper level my understanding of this page is incorrect? For I cannot see how "knowability" might refer to metaphysics / ontology and "objecthood" to epistemology, although, it is true, metaphysics, especially ontology, deals in the "knowability" of things; but are objects, in the traditionally metaphysical sense of the word, the same as objects? I wished the author had made the correlations between these four terms, in whichever 'compositional' direction, quite explicit and unequivocal.

Comment: "at a deeper level", maybe... According to the above commentary, in Kant's *KRV* the two "problems" are traeted as two sides of the same philosophical problem.

Comment: Great question!  Speaking as a "proceduralist", I might cast it as the distinction between Physics (constitution of reality) and Information Theory (how knowledge is attained and transmitted).

Comment: I believe you understood the text well. I have doubts about the correctness of what it says, but that's a different issue, which I'm not sure you're asking about.